# DOcplexException: Expecting linear constraint, got: docplex.mp.LogicalOrExpr

Tags: python, cplex, docplex

I want to write a conditional constraint using docplex. The constraint is:

```
if:
y[(i, j,k)]  == 1 or y[(j, i,k)]  == 1 

then:
g[i,j,k]==1
```

I implemented the code in docplex in this way:

```
mdl.add(mdl.if_then(mdl.logical_or(y[(i, j,k)]  == 1 ,y[(j, i,k)]  == 1 ),g[i,j,k]==1))
```

But when I run I get this error:

```
DOcplexException: Expecting linear constraint, got: docplex.mp.LogicalOrExpr(y_13_16_14 == 1,y_16_13_14 == 1)
```

How can I resolve the error?

Answer (score 0):

instead of if_then that needs linear constraints you could use truth values.

Let me give you a tiny example out of the [bus example](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-optimization-simple-python-alex-fleischer/)

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

mdl = Model(name='buses')
nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus30')
mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300, 'kids')
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)

mdl.solve()

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
   print(v," = ",v.solution_value)



#if then constraint
mdl.add(mdl.logical_or(nbbus40<=2,nbbus30<=2 )<=(nbbus30>=7))
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)

mdl.solve()

 

for v in mdl.iter_integer_vars():
    print(v," = ",v.solution_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Model.logical_or` returns an *expression* , equal to 1 if one of the argument is true; `Model.if_then` expects a *linear constraint*, so you need to convert the expression into a constraint, for example, write  `(Model.logical_or(a,b) ==1)`

In this small example, I state that c equals 1 when either a or b equal 1 (Note that logical operators such as logical_or or logical_and accept binary variables, no need to add '==1' there:

```
m = Model()
[a,b,c] = m.binary_var_list(keys=['a', 'b', 'c'], name=str)
# if a or b then c
m.add(m.if_then(m.logical_or(a,b) == 1, c==1))
m.maximize(a+b)
m.solve()
m.print_solution()
```

and the result is:

```
objective: 2
  "a"=1
  "b"=1
  "c"=1
```